# Good Performance of old MapDB 0.9.0

Tags: java, performance, database-performance, query-performance, mapdb

Why is the Performance of the older MapDB 0.9.0 release better than the newest MapDB 3.0 releases?

My division works with BigData and analytics and it's necessary to finish tasks very fast.

I've tried in a current Java software project an update to MapDB 3.0.3 but the newer version is too slow so I had to downgrade to the "old-fashioned" version.

I thank you in advance for your efforts

Comment: you should give more details. new version has different modes, you can use RandomAccessFiles or Channels, may be old version uses channels by default?